# strange issue reloading webpage very slow - but fast when force-reload

Tags: performance, .htaccess, typo3

I have a strange behaviour with one of my webpages:

When I load/reload the page, it takes ages for the TTFB (time to first byte) - sometimes up to 30 seconds.

Interestingly, when I do a force-reload (F5/holding down SHIFT-Key) the page loads instantly (TTFB under a second).

I tried to disable the cache-control in htaccess (I thought this might be the issue since shift-reload works fast), but it didn't help.

The page is a typo3 installation with multiple domains - none of the other domains has the same problem.
Also, it only happens with the homepage - all the subsequent pages load fine.

Any ideas???

Comment: I would recommend to run Xdebug Profiler and check, if it is problem on PHP/MySQL side or not.

Comment: I considered this already, but it requires extra installations on the server. I hope the hosting-company does this favor for me :)
Thanks for the hint, though!